# How to disable one-line formatting in VS Code?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

my `settings.json` file is:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "E:\\001_Kai_Duplicate\\Venv\\DesktopKubiK_Python37_TimeSeriesForecast\\python.exe",
    "python.pipenvPath": "<your-env-path>",   // if using pipenv
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Path": "<your-env-path>/bin/autopep8",
    "python.formatting.autopep8Args": [
      "--max-line-length",
      "70",
      "--aggressive",
    ],
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    // if using pylint
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    "python.linting.pylintPath": "<your-env-path>/bin/pylint",
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
      "--load-plugins",
      "pylint_django", // only if you are using django framework
      "--enable=W0614",
      "--enable= W0611"
    ],
    // if using flake8 (uncomment below lines and comment above block of settings of pylint
    // "python.linting.pylintEnabled": false,
    // "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    // "python.linting.flake8Path": "<your-env-path>/bin/flake8",
    // "python.linting.flake8Args": [
    //   "--max-line-length=130"
    // ],
    // to enable sort imports on save
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": true
    },
    // to add environment vars while opening a new vscode terminal (name:val)
    "terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
      "DJANGO_ENV": "DEV"
    },
    "[python]": {
      "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "python.linting.pylamaEnabled": true,
    "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  }
```

Currently when I save my .py file, all the attributes in a function will automatically be reformatted into one attribute per line. How can I disable that so attributes in a function will span across a certain length, and take a new line when it needs to be?

For example:

```
# This format
some_func(param1 = 'A', param2 = 'B', param3 = 'C',
          param4 = 'D')

# Not this format
some_func(
    param1 = 'A', 
    param2 = 'B', 
    param3 = 'C',      
    param4 = 'D'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have installed Prettier - Code formatter in VS Code, remove the extension and use some other formatter for python.